# Is it possible handle/debug requests hitting on remote EC2 instance with local java code?

Tags: java, spring-boot, debugging, amazon-ec2, remote-debugging

I'm writing java services deployed to EC2 instances on AWS.
We're based on micro-services architecture.

When a service talks to a bunch of other services, it makes local dev environment hard to set up, I have to spin up the dependent services on localhost, and configure to call local apis. Not to mention mocking other AWS resources, sqs, sns, dynamodb...

Imagine, I have micro service: A, B, C, D, E deployed on AWS EC2. A will call B, C, D, E.
When a request come and hits A service, I want to somehow "hijack" the A service to use the java code on my local machine instead of the jar deployed on that EC2 instance, and it should be able to stop at the break points set in my local IDE. After I press execute, the execution continues to call B, C, D, E services which are deployed on AWS EC2.

Is this even possible?

Comment: not sure how your microservices are detecting each other but in case you're using Eureka, you can run A on your local machine and direct it to the Eureka server. i believe that if your using other configurations you can still flow the same concept.

Comment: @AlonYampolski yes, I'm using eureka. Not sure what you mean direct it to the Eureka server? the local machine can get the other services ip address, but those are VPC internal, from the local machine, I think it won't be able to call them successfully considering Security group & VPC restrictions.

Comment: as i said, it's hard to provide a good answer while not knowing the full setup but i'll try to provide a general solution anyway. you can either enable your local machine in the security group or peer your VPC to another VPC and enable it there while redirecting your calls to the original one. as for the Eureka server, when you run springboot you need to specify its location and then you'll be registered on it.